# Changing the displayed format of Item Versions

Tags: sitecore-client

Is it possible to change the format shown in the Content Editor, of item version mode as "version 1", "version 2", etc rater than 1,2,3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to have Version 1, Version 2,... , Version N in Content editor view is possible but I don't see any advantage to have it.  I didn't change anything in the Sitecore database, I changed just the view from Content Editor.

I changed a bit the code to have "Version 1" instead to "1."

Please see below picture :

[image]

You need to make next changes :

Add a new class GalleryVersionsForm :

```
public class GalleryVersionsForm : GalleryForm
{
    /// <summary></summary>
    protected GalleryMenu Options;

    /// <summary></summary>
    protected Scrollbox Versions;

    /// <summary>
    /// Handles the message.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="message">The message.</param>
    public override void HandleMessage(Message message)
    {
        Assert.ArgumentNotNull(message, "message");
        if (message.Name == "event:click")
        {
            return;
        }
        base.Invoke(message, true);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Raises the load event.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e">The <see cref="T:System.EventArgs" /> instance containing the event data.</param>
    /// <remarks>
    /// This method notifies the server control that it should perform actions common to each HTTP
    /// request for the page it is associated with, such as setting up a database query. At this
    /// stage in the page lifecycle, server controls in the hierarchy are created and initialized,
    /// view state is restored, and form controls reflect client-side data. Use the IsPostBack
    /// property to determine whether the page is being loaded in response to a client postback,
    /// or if it is being loaded and accessed for the first time.
    /// </remarks>
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        Assert.ArgumentNotNull(e, "e");
        base.OnLoad(e);
        if (Context.ClientPage.IsEvent)
        {
            return;
        }
        Item currentItem = GalleryVersionsForm.GetCurrentItem();
        if (currentItem != null)
        {
            if (currentItem.IsFallback)
            {
                HtmlGenericControl htmlGenericControl = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
                htmlGenericControl.InnerText = Translate.Text("No version exists in the current language. You see a fallback version from '{0}' language.", new object[]
                {
                    currentItem.OriginalLanguage
                });
                htmlGenericControl.Attributes["class"] = "versionNumSelected";
                Context.ClientPage.AddControl(this.Versions, htmlGenericControl);
            }
            else
            {
                Item[] versions = currentItem.Versions.GetVersions();
                for (int i = versions.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                {
                    Item item = versions[i];
                    XmlControl xmlControl = ControlFactory.GetControl("Gallery.Versions.Option") as XmlControl;
                    Assert.IsNotNull(xmlControl, typeof(XmlControl), "Xml Control \"{0}\" not found", new object[]
                    {
                        "Gallery.Versions.Option"
                    });
                    Context.ClientPage.AddControl(this.Versions, xmlControl);
                    CultureInfo culture = Context.User.Profile.Culture;
                    string text = (item.Statistics.Updated == DateTime.MinValue) ? Translate.Text("[Not set]") : DateUtil.FormatShortDateTime(DateUtil.ToServerTime(item.Statistics.Updated), culture);
                    string text2 = (item.Statistics.UpdatedBy.Length == 0) ? "-" : item.Statistics.UpdatedBy;
                    string text3 ="Version "+ item.Version + ".";
                    if (item.Version.Number == currentItem.Version.Number)
                    {
                        text3 = "<div class=\"versionNumSelected\">" + text3 + "</div>";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        text3 = "<div class=\"versionNum\">" + text3 + "</div>";
                    }
                    xmlControl["Number"] = text3;
                    xmlControl["Header"] = Translate.Text("Modified <b>{0}</b> by <b>{1}</b>.", new object[]
                    {
                        text,
                        text2
                    });
                    xmlControl["Click"] = string.Format("item:load(id={0},language={1},version={2})", currentItem.ID, currentItem.Language, item.Version.Number);
                }
            }
        }
        Item item2 = Client.CoreDatabase.GetItem("/sitecore/content/Applications/Content Editor/Menues/Versions");
        if (item2 != null && item2.HasChildren)
        {
            string queryString = WebUtil.GetQueryString("id");
            this.Options.AddFromDataSource(item2, queryString, new CommandContext(currentItem));
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the current item.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The current item.</returns>
    private static Item GetCurrentItem()
    {
        string queryString = WebUtil.GetQueryString("db");
        string queryString2 = WebUtil.GetQueryString("id");
        Language language = Language.Parse(WebUtil.GetQueryString("la"));
        Sitecore.Data.Version version = Sitecore.Data.Version.Parse(WebUtil.GetQueryString("vs"));
        Database expr_3C = Factory.GetDatabase(queryString);
        Assert.IsNotNull(expr_3C, queryString);
        return expr_3C.Items[queryString2, language, version];
    }
    }
```

Above class is almost the same with class : **Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.Galleries.Versions.GalleryVersionsForm**

Only one change is :    **string text3 ="Version " + item.Version + ".";**

instead of      **string text3 = item.Version + ".";**

To use your code you need to modify  \Website\sitecore\shell\Applications\Content Manager\Galleries\Versions\Gallery Versions.xml .

You have to change Codebeside section to :

```
<CodeBeside Type="YourNamespace.GalleryVersionsForm,YourAssembly">
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Will implement this and shall confirm.

Comment: please mark it correct answer

Answer (score 2):

### No it isn't

Sitecore treats `Version` internally as an integer. To change this behaviour would cascade changes all the way through the system, all the way down to database level.

[image]